# ACTION_CALL acting as ACTION_DIAL on Nexus/Android 4.3 for numbers beginning 08

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I have an application with a single edittext and button in its layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="phone" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Dial" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and a `MainActivity` that extends `Activity` and does

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      String strNumber = editText1.getText().toString();
      if (!strNumber.equals("")) 
      {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + strNumber));
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    }      
  });
}
```

For numbers that don't start '08...', it calls the number as expected.  For numbers that start '08...', it brings up the dialler with the number filled in instead.  How can I stop this?  It doesn't appear to be a setting on the phone, at least not so far as I can see, but  I tested this on a 4.3 emulator and it worked as expected.  I don't have another 4.3 phone to test it on.  My 4.2.2 HTC One dials as expected, as do all my older test devices.

I can dial the 0800 numbers directly, or by hitting the call button after the app brings the dialler up, so they're not being blocked entirely, and I get the same effect without a sim in the phone, so that's not it.

---

ETA: I can get around this by prefixing 08 numbers with "," which causes a slight pause before dialling but otherwise works.  That doesn't really explain why it's happening, though.

Answer (score 2):

I have no 4.3 phone to make a test.
However, I took a look at source code of [OutgoingCallBroadcaster](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/phone/OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java#OutgoingCallBroadcaster), whose role is described as follows:

> OutgoingCallBroadcaster receives CALL and CALL_PRIVILEGED Intents, and broadcasts the ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent which allows other applications to monitor, redirect, or prevent the outgoing call.

Its *processIntent(Intent i)* method contains a fragment (around line 493) changing intent's action into ACTION_DIAL, if number is deemed as "potentially emergency".

To summarize, Android has a policy of intercepting ACTION_CALL with a dialer pad. Not quite sure why that happened in your case, though.